# Edit the Design elements in PySimpleGUI and Button Malfunction

Tags: python, pandas, pysimplegui

I am Building a DB Comparator Tool which compares on the basis of user input and Displays the result Using Datacompy.

It's divided into two windows

1. Get the Details from user
2. Give the Comparison results to User

how can I create a drop down box.
on the Second window just below the FileBrowse element I want to create a drop down which holds the value from the excel file which user is going to upload for example

Excel will hold two columns ( Table Name and SQL )
I want to bring all the Table Name to the Drop Down Box

how can i proceed on that ?

The Code is working absolutely fine but it's the design i am struggling upon and the few open question to make the Tool somewhat perfect.

Design I want to achieve:
[image: Design which i want]

If you see at attached image that what I am trying to achieve but it seems like not working for me

Here are my open questions :

1. How can i design according to what I am imagining
2. Exit Button on second window is not working it doesn't close's the window instead it goes into a not responding state
3. How can I allign the Text Box ?

here's my code ( Pardon me for Indentation it's is little wrong because i copy and pasted here  ) :

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import re
import datacompy
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd

supportedextensions = ['csv','xlsx', 'xlsm' ,'json']





#Database Details Layout   
DB_creds_one = [
    [ sg.Text("UserName"), sg.In(size=(25, 1), enable_events=True, key="-uname_db1-") ],
    [ sg.Text("Password"), sg.In(size=(25, 1), enable_events=True, key="-pword_db1-") ],
    [ sg.Text("Hostname"), sg.In(size=(25, 1), enable_events=True, key="-hname_db1-") ],
    [ sg.Text("Server"), sg.In(size=(25, 1), enable_events=True, key="-sname_db1-") ],
    [ sg.Text("Port"), sg.In(size=(25, 1), enable_events=True, key="-port_db1-") ],
    [ sg.B('Test Con1', key='B1') ],
    ]
db_creds_two = [
    [ sg.Text("UserName"), sg.In(size=(None,5),enable_events=True, key="-uname_db2-") ],
    [ sg.Text("Password"), sg.In(size=(None,5), enable_events=True, key="-pword_db2-") ],
    [ sg.Text("Hostname"), sg.In(size=(None,5), enable_events=True, key="-hname_db2-") ],
    [ sg.Text("Server"), sg.In(size=(None,5), enable_events=True, key="-sname_db2-") ],
    [ sg.Text("Port"), sg.In(size=(None,5), enable_events=True, key="-port_db2-") ],
    [ sg.B('Test Con2',key='B2') ],
]

layoutprefile = [
[ 
    sg.Column(DB_creds_one),
    sg.VSeperator(),
    sg.Column(db_creds_two),
],

[sg.Output(size=(80, 25), key='-output-')],
[sg.Submit('Proceed'), sg.Button('Exit')]
]

window = sg.Window("DB Comparator", layoutprefile)

# default values at start
secondwindow = True
Test_DB1 = False
Test_DB2 = False

while True:    # The Event Loop
    event, values = window.read()
    # print(event, values)  # debug
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit' or event == 'Cancel':
        secongwindow = False
        break

    
        
    

if secondwindow == False:
    exit()
else :  
layoutpostfile = [
    [sg.Text('File 1'), sg.InputText(), sg.FileBrowse()],
    [sg.Output(size=(80, 25), key='-output-')],
    [sg.Submit('Compare'), sg.Button('Exit')]
]

compare_window = sg.Window('File Compare', layoutpostfile)

filecheck = False


        
window.close()
```

EDITS :

1. What more can i add into the tool
2. How can i Improvise the Code

Comment: Better to reduce your code to only about GUI if your issue is on GUI only.

Comment: Addressed Thank you

Comment: two last questions (in `EDITS`) better fit to similar portal [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: second window has button `EXIT` but I don't see code which would close it. I don't see `compare_window.close()`

Comment: you have wrong indentations in code. I don't see how you open second window - there is no function for it. So I can't run it to see problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what your question, following code for your reference only.

Set option `size` with same value for `sg.Text` to keep all `sg.text` with same size.
Add option `modal=True` in `sg.Window` to keep parent window no accept keyboard and mouse event.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def popup():
    layout = [
        [sg.Text('File 1'), sg.InputText(), sg.FileBrowse()],
        [sg.Output(size=(80, 25), key='-output-')],
        [sg.Submit('Compare'), sg.Button('Exit')],
    ]
    window = sg.Window('File Compare', layout, modal=True)
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        print(event, values)
        if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
            break
    window.close()
    return

sg.theme('DarkBlue3')
sg.set_options()

DB_creds_one = [
    [ sg.Text("UserName", size=(10, 1)), sg.In(size=(25, 1), enable_events=True, key="-uname_db1-") ],
    [ sg.Text("Password", size=(10, 1)), sg.In(size=(25, 1), enable_events=True, key="-pword_db1-") ],
    [ sg.Text("Hostname", size=(10, 1)), sg.In(size=(25, 1), enable_events=True, key="-hname_db1-") ],
    [ sg.Text("Server",   size=(10, 1)), sg.In(size=(25, 1), enable_events=True, key="-sname_db1-") ],
    [ sg.Text("Port",     size=(10, 1)), sg.In(size=(25, 1), enable_events=True, key="-port_db1-") ],
    [ sg.B('Test Con1', key='B1') ],
]
db_creds_two = [
    [ sg.Text("UserName", size=(10, 1)), sg.In(size=(None,5), enable_events=True, key="-uname_db2-") ],
    [ sg.Text("Password", size=(10, 1)), sg.In(size=(None,5), enable_events=True, key="-pword_db2-") ],
    [ sg.Text("Hostname", size=(10, 1)), sg.In(size=(None,5), enable_events=True, key="-hname_db2-") ],
    [ sg.Text("Server",   size=(10, 1)), sg.In(size=(None,5), enable_events=True, key="-sname_db2-") ],
    [ sg.Text("Port",     size=(10, 1)), sg.In(size=(None,5), enable_events=True, key="-port_db2-") ],
    [ sg.B('Test Con2',key='B2') ],
]

layoutprefile = [
    [
        sg.Column(DB_creds_one),
        sg.VSeperator(),
        sg.Column(db_creds_two),
    ],
    [sg.Output(size=(80, 25), key='-output-')],
    [sg.Submit('Proceed'), sg.Button('Exit')],
]

window = sg.Window("DB Comparator", layoutprefile)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit' or event == 'Cancel':
        secongwindow = False
        break
    elif event == 'Proceed':
        result = popup()

window.close()
```